# What is the Amazon Browser in 14.04

Tags: unity, default-browser

In a recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, there is an Amazon browser in the Unity sidebar and a "Browser" in Dash. I don't know how to find the source and name of these browsers. I'd expect that they're based on Firefox / seamonkey, but I'm not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The *Amazon* icon is not a browser. It is a web app. It is just the *Amazon* site, embedded in the `webapp-container` process. *Browser* in the dash, is the new browser for Ubuntu, based on *Oxide* which is based on *Chrome*'s engine.